# Black hole Generation and Location inside ship in movie Event horizon?

Tags: movie, wormhole, event-horizon

In the movie *Event Horizon* the ship uses "Core" to generate a black hole which in turn opens a wormhole which is in turn used to travel long distances. The core location is inside the ship,if one needs to go through a wormhole it should be created outside the ship and not within the ship. How can the ship pass through a wormhole created within itself?

Comment: Science!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the [movie script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Event-Horizon.html), Weir explicitly explains how the drive works; The [swirling metal thing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHKfoWh8t6o&feature=youtu.be&t=48s) is used to focus the gravity of the black hole in front of the ship, which then travels through the 'gateway' created.

> **MILLER :** *What is in the Core?*
>
> **WEIR:** *A black hole.*
>
> The crew stares at him, stunned.
>
> **WEIR:** *That's how the gravity drive works, you see: it **focuses the black hole's immense gravitational power** to create the gateway. That's how the Event Horizon travels faster than light.*

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain but I seem to remember at the end when the ship went back into hyperspace it didn't actually move. It was there one minute and then gone.

Which suggests to me it's not so much opening a wormhole as it is creating a bubble around the ship like the warp drive in Star Trek.